# How do I register ZF2 Helpers with zfc-twig 1.2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, twig

I've had to downgrade from 1.2 to 1.1.5 to get my view helpers to work again.

Under 1.2, they simply return blank; can't tell if they're even being hit.  Is there a magic step required to make this work?

**EDIT**

An example of a helper I am having a tough time including with 1.2, is a navigation helper that has this configuration in its Module.php:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'navigation' => function ($sm) {
                $helper = new View\Helper\Navigation($sm->getServiceLocator()->get('config'), null);
                return $helper;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

I've tried adding either of these two following configurations without luck:

```
/**
 * Twig
 */
'zfctwig' => array(

    'disable_zf_model' => false,

    'helper_manager' => array(
        'configs' => array(
            'Application\View\Helper\Navigation' => function( $sm ){
                $helper = new View\Helper\Navigation($sm->getServiceLocator()->get('config'), null);
                return $helper;
             },
        ),
    ),

),
```

…or…

```
/**
 * Twig
 */
'zfctwig' => array(

    'disable_zf_model' => false,

    'helper_manager' => array(
        'configs' => array(
            'Application\View\Helper\Navigation' => function( $sm ){
                $helper = new View\Helper\Navigation($sm->getServiceLocator()->get('config'), null);
                return $helper;
             },
        ),
    ),

),
```

Neither seem to work.  I am trying to invoke this helper through this line in my layout.twig:

```
{{ navigation() }}
```

ZFCTwig version d8450076d5297de21dffc568870f6e605ead41e9

Answer (score 2):

ZfcTwig 1.2 does not get view helpers from the `Zend\View\HelperPluginManager` anymore, due to some incompatibility issues. You can see a better explanation [here](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcTwig#gotchas).

Now ZfcTwig uses its own `HelperPluginManager`, so you need to register your view helpers in `ZfcTwig\View\HelperPluginManager` config, like that:

```
return array(
    'zfctwig' => array(
       'helper_manager' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
                'MyHelper' => 'MyApp\View\Helper\MyHelper',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay - still not working for me.  I added more details to my question.  I tried searching the zfctwig source for helper_manager and can't find any references either, aside from the stock config file which references a 'config' member instead of 'invokables'.

Comment: Since you're setting a factory to your view helper, you must use the `factories` key instead of `config`.